# Help Center for Badges > Tags shows incorrect info

Tags: discussion, tags, tag-badges

Help Center for Badges > Tags shows incorrect info.

[**Help Center > Badges > Tags**](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/5239/selenium-webdriver) for `selenium-webdriver` shows *gold* awarded 2 times.

Where as [**Top users**](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/selenium-webdriver/topusers) for `selenium-webdriver` shows 4 users with votes above 1K.

Is it a bug?

Comment: There are two criteria for the badge: votes & number of answers.

Comment: @Mat I meant votes. Gold tag is offered at 1K votes.

Comment: Please read the info on the page you linked again: _"Earn at least 1000 total score for at least 200 non-community wiki answers in the selenium-webdriver tag"_ It clearly states at least 200 answers

Comment: all is correct, 2 people still have less than 200 answers, so only 2 gold

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A score of 1000 or more is **not enough**. You missed an important detail on the page you linked, which lists **two** criteria that need to be met:

> Earn at least 1000 total score **for at least 200 non-community wiki answers**

Bold emphasis mine. Two of those 4 users have given fewer than 200 qualifying answers, so they have not yet met the criteria for a gold badge.

So no, there is no bug here, those users simply need to write a few more qualifying answers (or additional posts that they already wrote answers to but currently not tagged as [selenium-webdriver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/selenium-webdriver) are edited to add that tag).

Comment: Thanks, clears all of my doubts.